# como se crean las url dinamicas cuando se buscan datos a traves de un filtro?

Tags: angular, filtro

estoy creando un pequeño filtro para una pequeña tienda pero tengo una gran duda. Estoy usando Angular se me generó la duda de como se crean las rutas (url's dinámicas) a medida que se van filtrando los datos.

Por ejemplo, en la web de [mercadolibre.com](https://www.mercadolibre.com.ve/) a medida que vas filtrando se van agregando esas palabras a la url así:

si coloco audífonos entonces la url cambia a: `https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ve/audifonos#D[A:audifonos]`

si posteriormente filtro por estado, por ejemplo: Carabobo, entonces ahora la URL se modifica a:

`https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ve/carabobo/audifonos`

entonces si luego decido ir a "atras" en el navegador regresa a la ultima url visitada que sería en este caso esta:  `https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ve/audifonos#D[A:audifonos]` .

Como se logra esto en Angular? imagino que es haciendo uso de las rutas, pero no estoy claro en como lograrlo, de la forma en que lo estoy haciendo ahora es la siguiente:

voy creando una lista de parametros a medida que el usuario va agregando filtros, y esta lista la envío al back para que haga la consulta y me retorne el resultado, pero no se si esa sería una buena práctica ya que las Url's no se modifican, y no hay ese dinamismo que tienen todas las páginas que tienen un filtro.

Espero alguien me pueda orientar en este problema, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el siguiente codigo para obtener el id del item en el componente donde se filtrara, a partir de ese id tendrias que hacer un **GET** a tu base de datos para obtener los datos de tu item.

```
  import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  Public idItem: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.idItem = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
  }
```

Ahora para tu filtro podrias redireccionar al componente donde se filtrara el item usando el modulo **Router** de angular.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

onFilter(item: string): void {
 this.router.navigate(['/audifonos/', item]);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero en ese caso tendría que crear n componentes (audífonos, teclados, etc. ) ? a lo que me refiero es que por ejemplo, tu entra ````mercadoLibre.com``` y te abre el siguiente link: ```https://www.mercadolibre.com.ve/#from=homecom``` que es el home, si escribes audifonos la url cambia a ```https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ve/audifonos#D[A:audifonos]``` luego si filtras por ciudad, por ejemplo, carabobo, ahora la url cambia a ```https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ve/carabobo/audifonos``` y si filtro  usado: ```https://listado.mercadolibre.com.ve/carabobo/usados/audifonos_NoIndex_True```

Comment: No es necesario crear n componentes, podria ser dinamico si accedes al padre de la ruta que contiene el id del item para posteriromente hacer la consulta, añadiendole **parent** las veces que quieres recorrer. **this.activatedRoute.snapshot.parent.params.id;**